# iOS9: Need to recompile to be compatible?

Tags: ios9, app-transport-security

I tried to run my app with XCode7 (GM) and iOS9 and recognized that I couldn't create a SSL-connection. It still works in iOS8.
Error: "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made". The reason is that Apple enforces developers to use App transport security.

But does this mean that apps that are currently in the store will not work anymore on iOS9 and I will get a lot of negative feedback next week after the launch of iOS9?
Or will it happen after I have builded with XCode7?

Answer (score 1):

Current apps already in the app store or submitted using Xcode 6 and the iOS8 SDK will continue to function as-is. This will only be an issue for apps submitted using Xcode 7 and the iOS9 SDK.  And even then, you can disable ATS by adding the following to your app's plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
  <true/>  
</dict>
```

Comment: Saved me hundreds of hours work! More convenient you can directly set it in Xcode editor on the plist. Just search for "APP Transport Security Settings".

Answer (score 0):

I think it is optional right now. You can disable that by adding some lines to Info.plist. (If it wasn't optional, even Twitter won't work properly :) There are a lot of images, which has non ssl link) You can use [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4988) link to disable it. Also, your current apps will continue to work with iOS9 automatically.